# How to put a media controller on pull up notification panel in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am playing an MP3 by using AVPlayer. The mp3 is playing in background mode also. I want to access the music from the pull up notification panel like any other media player app does.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, Firstly read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/index.html)

If you are using `backgroundMode` you are initiazing a `AVAudioSession`so you can just add it to info center.

You can follow this [blog](http://jaysonlane.net/tech-blog/2012/04/lock-screen-now-playing-with-mpnowplayinginfocenter/)

And this is how I did it

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter* mpic = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSMutableDictionary *songDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (songInfo.detail.songTitle) {
        [songDictionary setObject:songInfo.detail.songTitle forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    } else {
        [songDictionary setObject:songInfo.visibleName forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    }
    if (songInfo.detail.artist) {
        [songDictionary setObject:songInfo.detail.artist forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    }
    if (songInfo.detail.album) {
        [songDictionary setObject:songInfo.detail.album forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    }
    if (songInfo.detail.duration) {
        double durationDouble = CMTimeGetSeconds([APPDELEGATE.session.playerItem duration]);
        [songDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:durationDouble] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];

        double playbackDouble = CMTimeGetSeconds([APPDELEGATE.session.playerItem currentTime]);
        [songDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:playbackDouble] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime];

    }
    if(mpic) {
        [mpic setNowPlayingInfo:songDictionary];
    }
```

Comment: yes. It was easy. got the answer from google before you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am too late to answer on this post but i did not found any solution about this problem when i was searching on it. Check this and just add in your code, your song will be show in notification panel .

```
//Add these lines where you are initializing your player and creating items for it.
_appdel.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[_appdel.player currentItem]];
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
//if it is a remote control event handle it correctly
if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay)
    {
        NSLog(@"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay");
        //[[AppMusicPlayer sharedService]playAudio];
        [_appdel.player play];
    }
    else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause)
    {
        NSLog(@"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause");
        //[[AppMusicPlayer sharedService]pauseAudio];
        [_appdel.player pause];
    }
    else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause)
    {
        NSLog(@"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause");
    }
    else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack)
    {
        NSLog(@"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlToggleNext");

    }
    else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack)
    {
        NSLog(@"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPrevious");

    }
}
}
```

its working on my side and Hopefully it will work for you thanks..